# How to convert JSON array to CSV using Node.js?

Tags: json, node.js, csv, express

I want to convert json which has value array.
**response.json**

```
{
"rows": [
[
  "New Visitor",
  "(not set)",
  "(not set)",      
  "0"
],
[
  "New Visitor",
  "(not set)",
  "(not set)",
  "mobile"      
],
[
  "New Visitor",
  "(not set)",
  "(not set)",
  "mobile"    
],
  [
    "New Visitor",
    "(not set)",
    "(not set)",
   "mobile",      
  ]
 ]
}
```

Now i want to convert this data into.
**name.csv**

```
 "New Visitor","(not set)","(not set)","0"
 "New Visitor","(not set)","(not set)","mobile"        
 "New Visitor","(not set)","(not set)","mobile"    
 "New Visitor","(not set)","(not set)","mobile"
```

Please give me suggetions using Node.js.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### Do it yourself like this:

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');

let myObj = {
  "rows": [
    [
      "New , Visitor",
      "(not set)",
      "(not set)",
      "0"
    ],
    [
      "New Visitor",
      "(not set)",
      "(not set)",
      "mobile"
    ],
    [
      "New Visitor",
      "(not set)",
      "(not set)",
      "mobile"
    ],
    [
      "New Visitor",
      "(not set)",
      "(not set)",
      "mobile",
    ]
  ]
}

// 1. One way - if you want the results to be in double quotes and you have comas inside

// choose another string to temporally replace commas if necessary
let stringToReplaceComas = '!!!!';

myObj.rows.map((singleRow) => {
  singleRow.map((value, index) => {
    singleRow[index] = value.replace(/,/g, stringToReplaceComas);
  })
})

let csv = `"${myObj.rows.join('"\n"').replace(/,/g, '","')}"`;
// // or like this
// let csv = `"${myObj.rows.join('"\n"').split(',').join('","')}"`;

csv = csv.replace(new RegExp(`${stringToReplaceComas}`, 'g'), ',');

// // 2. Another way - if you don't need the double quotes in the generated csv and you don't have comas in rows' values
// let csv = myObj.rows.join('\n')

fs.writeFile('name.csv', csv, 'utf8', function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Some error occured - file either not saved or corrupted file saved.');
  } else {
    console.log('It\'s saved!');
  }
});
```

### Use libraries

ex. https://github.com/mrodrig/json-2-csv, https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv, https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv-stringify

an example using json-2-csv (https://github.com/mrodrig/json-2-csv)

```
'use strict';

const converter = require('json-2-csv');

let myObj = {
  "rows": [
    {
      value1: "New Visitor",
      value2: "(not set)",
      value3: "(not set)",
      value4: "0"
    },
    {
      value1: "New Visitor",
      value2: "(not set)",
      value3: "(not set)",
      value4: "mobile"
    },
    {
      value1: "New Visitor",
      value2: "(not set)",
      value3: "(not set)",
      value4: "mobile"
    },
    {
      value1: "New Visitor",
      value2: "(not set)",
      value3: "(not set)",
      value4: "mobile",
    }
  ]
}

let json2csvCallback = function (err, csv) {
    if (err) throw err;
    fs.writeFile('name.csv', csv, 'utf8', function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Some error occured - file either not saved or corrupted file saved.');
      } else {
        console.log('It\'s saved!');
      }
    });
};

converter.json2csv(myObj.rows, json2csvCallback, {
  prependHeader: false      // removes the generated header of "value1,value2,value3,value4" (in case you don't want it)
});
```

an example using csv-stringify (https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv-stringify)

```
'use strict';

var stringify = require('csv-stringify');
var fs = require('fs');

let myObj = {
  "rows": [
    [
      "New Visitor",
      "(not set)",
      "(not set)",
      "0"
    ],
    [
      "New Visitor",
      "(not set)",
      "(not set)",
      "mobile"
    ],
    [
      "New Visitor",
      "(not set)",
      "(not set)",
      "mobile"
    ],
    [
      "New Visitor",
      "(not set)",
      "(not set)",
      "mobile",
    ]
  ]
}

stringify(myObj.rows, function(err, output) {
  fs.writeFile('name.csv', output, 'utf8', function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Some error occured - file either not saved or corrupted file saved.');
    } else {
      console.log('It\'s saved!');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer!its really helps me.can you write same code using node-csv library since i want to read to read about 1GB of Data.

Comment: I've edited the above example, you can test it, tell me if it works

Comment: Be careful about using regular expressions to generate CSV files. The JSON values could include commas as part of the values, which would cause trouble. For example: `[ "Visitor, New", "(not set)", …]` would become `"New"," Visitor","(not set)", …`. I do like your use of the single `.join` on the parent array, however, and I've updated my answer to reference your use of this technique.

Comment: yeah! thats why asked for pre defined library!

Comment: the library "csv-stringify" covers that case ("Visitor, New")

Comment: I've edited my code, now the coma case is covered, thanx for the brief @gfullam, you've made me realize there's a bug in the project I'm currently working on ...

Comment: After several hours trying to use the library and I ended up write my own. https://github.com/KhanhPham2411/simple-node-csv

import { SimpleNodeCsv } from './simple-node-csv';

SimpleNodeCsv.obj2csv({a: 1, b:2}, ",");

// output
// "a","b"
// 1,2

Answer (score 15):

## Three easy steps: Read. Convert. Write.

**Step 1: Read.**

If you need to read the JSON from a file (as indicated by your inclusion of the filename `response.json` in your post), you will require the [Node.js FileSystem API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html):

```
const fs = require('fs');                          // Require Node.js FileSystem API.
const JSONFile = fs.readFileSync('response.json'); // Read the file synchronously.
```

*Note: If you prefer, you can read the file asynchronously with [`fs.readFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback) and perform the conversion in a callback function.*

**Step 2: Convert.**

Whether you read your JSON from a local file or GET it from a server, you will need to parse it into a Plain Old JavaScript Object first using the [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method:

```
const JSONasPOJO = JSON.parse(JSONFile); // Parse JSON into POJO.
```

<s>Then perform a series of joins on the child arrays and parent array:</s>
*SEE **EDIT** BELOW*

```
/* THIS IS UNNECESSARY FOR "COMMA" SEPARATED VALUES
const CSVString = JSONasPOJO
    .rows                    // Get `rows`, which is an array.
    .map(                    // Map returns a new array.
        row => row.join(',') // Each child array becomes a comma-separated string.  
     )                    
    .join('\n');             // Parent array becomes a newline-separated string...
                             // ...of comma-separated strings.
                             // It is now a single CSV string!
*/
```

**EDIT:**

*While the previous code certainly works, it is unnecessary to use `.map` and `.join` on the child arrays. As [@Relu demonstrates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38245177/2502532), a single `.join` on the parent array is sufficient because JavaScript will automatically convert the child arrays into comma-separated strings by default since `.join` must return a string and cannot contain any child arrays.*

*You could use the above pattern if you want to join the child arrays with something other than a comma.*

*Otherwise:*

```
var CSVString = JSONasPOJO.rows.join('\n'); // Array becomes a newline-separated...
                                            // ...string of comma-separated strings.
                                            // It is now a single CSV string!
```

*Here, we can see that conversion in action:*

```js
const JSONasPOJO = {
  "rows": [
    [
      "New Visitor",
      "(not set)",
      "(not set)",      
      "0"
    ],
    [
      "New Visitor",
      "(not set)",
      "(not set)",
      "mobile"      
    ],
    [
      "New Visitor",
      "(not set)",
      "(not set)",
      "mobile"    
    ],
    [
      "New Visitor",
      "(not set)",
      "(not set)",
      "mobile" // NOTE: Here I removed a trailing comma,
               // ...which is invalid JSON!
    ]
  ]
}

const CSVString = JSONasPOJO.rows.join('\n');

console.log(CSVString);
```

**Step 3: Write.**

Using the FileSystem API again, write to a file, and log an error or a success message:

```
fs.writeFile('name.csv', CSVString, err => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log('FILE SUCCESSFULLY WRITTEN!\n');
});
```

*Note: Here, I demonstrate the asynchronous pattern using a callback to log my error and success messages. If you prefer, you can write the file synchronously with [`fs.writeFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options).*

### Putting it all together

*I like to add plenty of `console.log()` messages to my Node.js scripts.*

```
const fs = require('fs');

const inFilename  = 'response.json',
      outFilename = 'name.csv';

console.log(`Preparing to read from ${inFilename} …`);

const JSONContents = fs.readFileSync(inFilename);

console.log(`READ:\n${JSONContents}`);
console.log('Preparing to parse as JSON …');

const JSONasPOJO = JSON.parse(JSONContents);

console.log(`PARSED:\n${JSONasPOJO}`);
console.log('Preparing to convert into CSV …');

const CSVString = JSONasPOJO.rows.join('\n');

console.log(`CONVERTED:\n${CSVString}`);
console.log(`Preparing to write to ${outFilename} …`);

fs.writeFile(outFilename, CSVString, err => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log('FILE SUCCESSFULLY WRITTEN!');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about you guys, but i like small packages that just work as expected without a lot of extra configuration, try using jsonexport, i think its the best module for this, works really well with objects, arrays, .. and its fast!

Install

```
npm i --save jsonexport
```

Usage

```
const jsonexport = require('jsonexport');
const fs = require('fs');

jsonexport([{
  value1: "New Visitor",
  value2: "(not set)",
  value3: "(not set)",
  value4: "0"
},
{
  value1: "New Visitor",
  value2: "(not set)",
  value3: "(not set)",
  value4: "mobile"
},
{
  value1: "New Visitor",
  value2: "(not set)",
  value3: "(not set)",
  value4: "mobile"
},
{
  value1: "New Visitor",
  value2: "(not set)",
  value3: "(not set)",
  value4: "mobile",
}], function(err, csv) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  fs.writeFile('output.csv', csv, function(err) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log('output.csv saved');
  });
});
```

https://github.com/kauegimenes/jsonexport

Comment: you may want to note that this library is your own library. It goes against site conduct to not disclose this

Comment: good library! thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

I would like to share the easiest way to build a csv string from a json array:

```js
const data = [
  { a: 1, b: new Date(), c: 'a text' },
  {
    a: 1, b: new Date(), c: `string
  with
  return
  carrier
  and emoji 
  `
  }
]

const header = Object.keys(data[0]).map(_ => JSON.stringify(_)).join(';') + '\n'
const outData = data.reduce((acc, row) => {
  return acc + Object.values(row).map(_ => JSON.stringify(_)).join(';') + '\n'
}, header)

console.log(outData)
```

Will print this string:

```
"a";"b";"c"
1;"2020-03-25T08:49:04.280Z";"a text"
1;"2020-03-25T08:49:04.280Z";"string\n  with\n  return\n  carrier\n  and emoji \n  "
```

Comment: Thanks Manuel. I tried one by one all the answers of this question and only yours worked. Maybe we can convert it to a library :)

Answer (score 1):

After several hours trying to use the library and I ended up write my own.
https://github.com/KhanhPham2411/simple-node-csv

```
import { SimpleNodeCsv } from './simple-node-csv';

SimpleNodeCsv.obj2csv({a: 1, b:2}, ",");

// output
// "a","b"
// 1,2
```